# Can't resolve variables from ui-router resolve object into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` in my app.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvide.state('State1', {
       url:'/State1',
       resolve: {
          data: function(Service){
              return Service.init();
          }
       },
       views: {
            "header": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/header.tpl.html'
            },
            "center":{
                  templateUrl: 'views/center.tpl.html'
            },
            "footer": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/footer.tpl.html'
            }
          }
       }
    })
}
]);
```

I tried to load a json file from the server and resolve it in the router. 
In the `resolve` object, I call to my service that is responsible for returning promise.

**Service.js:**

```
app.service("Service", ['$rootscope', '$http', function($rootscope, $http){
var promise;
this.init = function(){
    promise = this.loadData();
    return promise;
};

this.loadData = function(){
    var url = "users/getData/json.json";
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
         return response.data;
    }, function(error){
        alert(error);
        })
    };
}])
```

**center.tpl.html:**

```
<aside id="first-item" ng-controller="FirstController as firstController">
     <first-directive>
</aside>
<aside id="second-item" ng-controller="SecondController as secondController">
     <second-directive>
</aside>
```

This is the controller to which I would like to get the resolved data.

**FirstController.js:**

```
app.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'data', function($scope, data){
     this.myData = data;
}]);
```

I got the next error: `Unknown provider: dataProvider < - data`. Why?

Comment: you want to get the data from the service?

Answer (score 1):

since promise is never resolved before returning. try this one.

```
app.service("Service", ['$rootscope', '$http', function($rootscope, $http){
var promise;
this.init = function(){
   return this.loadData();
};

this.loadData = function(){
    var url = "users/getData/json.json";
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
         return response.data;
    }, function(error){
        alert(error);
        })
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) docs:

> // The controller waits for every one of the above items to be
>   // completely resolved before instantiation. For example, the
>   // controller will not instantiate until promiseObj's promise has
>   // been resolved. Then those objects are injected into the controller
>   // and available for use.

It is cleared that the resolved variables will only be available in the controllers defined in the state config. You can not resolve those variables in a normal controller and you are trying to use `data` from your state config in your controller and hence you are getting that error.

But, to get those data in your `FirstController`, you can do like this:

```
app.config('$stateProvider', ['$rootScope', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvide.state('State1', {
        url: '/State1',
        resolve: {
            data: function (Service) {
                var data = Service.init();
                $rootScope.$broadcast("dataReceivedFoo", {data: data});
                return data;
            }
        },
        views: {
            "header": {
                templateUrl: 'views/header.tpl.html'
            },
            "center": {
                templateUrl: 'views/center.tpl.html'
            },
            "footer": {
                templateUrl: 'views/footer.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    })
}]);
```

And, then read in your controller:

```
app.controller('FirstController', ['$scope' function($scope){
    $scope.$on("dataReceivedFoo", function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    })
}]);
```

Basically, we are broadcasting the data from your state configuration and then receiving in your `FirstController`.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `controller: 'FirstController'` line to state will solve the problem.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvide.state('State1', {
       url:'/State1',
       controller: 'FirstController',
       resolve: {
          data: function(Service){
              return Service.init();
          }
       },
       views: {
            "header": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/header.tpl.html'
            },
            "center":{
                  templateUrl: 'views/center.tpl.html'
            },
            "footer": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/footer.tpl.html'
            }
          }
       }
    })
}
]);
```

> **Resolve**
>
> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data
>   that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and
>   converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the
>   $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.
>
> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains
>   key/value pairs of:
>
> **key** – {string}: **a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>   controller**.
>
> factory - {string|function}: If string, then it is an
>
> > alias for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and
> >     the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a
> >     promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its
> >     value is injected into the controller.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki